# dyld: DYLD_ environment variables being ignored because main executable (/usr/bin/sudo) is setuid or setgid

Tags: macos, command-line, sudo, osx-mountain-lion, dyld

since an update to 10.8 I get the following error, when trying to do a sudo command, which is pretty annoying.

```
dyld: DYLD_ environment variables being ignored because main executable (/usr/bin/sudo) is setuid or setgid
```

What does that have to mean? I hope anyone can help.

Comment: For me, I found that if you install XCode and probably also the Command Line Tools component, that this warning stops.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

This seems to be a bug introduced in 10.8, see [this report](http://openradar.appspot.com/11894054). As far as I can tell, the only workaround is not setting DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH or LD_LIBRARY_PATH by default, but only when needed.

Comment: Ok. In my .bash_profile I just commented out `export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/local/mysql/lib:$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH`. I don't quite know what I did there, but at least this annoying message stopped. Hope this'll get fixed soon

Comment: @eneskaya: I think I read somewhere that there used to be buggy mysql versions that had the wrong path to the libraries embedded. Setting that DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH was the solution. If mysql still works for you, I guess they fixed it.

Comment: @eneskaya: Are you using mySQL? Does mySQL still work for you?

Comment: I added `unset LD_LIBRARY_PATH` in `~/.profile`, and the annoying message disappeared.

Comment: This will break sql for me if I do that.

Comment: I would recommend using the sudo function below: sudo () { ( unset LD_LIBRARY_PATH DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH; exec command sudo $* ) }. It works in BASH, as well, and is elegant. Just place it in your .bashrc and source it (. .bashrc).

Answer (score 20):

In zsh:

```
sudo () { ( unset LD_LIBRARY_PATH DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH; exec command sudo $* ) }
```

This spawns a sub-shell in which the environment variables sudo complains about are unset, and then executes sudo (via exec so that the now-unecessary parent shell exits immediately).

I'll leave it as an exercise to the reader to port to bash, et al.

Comment: Tried putting this line of command in /etc/bashrc (need `chmod +w /etc/bashrc` to allow write permission) and the warning message is gone, thanks!

Answer (score 7):

Not sure where the official solve is for this, but I solved it with this  bashrc hack, because I couldn't deal with seeing that damn warning any longer.

## put this in the /etc/bashrc or wherever yours lives.

```
# set DYLD_* for my normal programs
DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH='..'
 
# set an alternative sudo
thesudo()
{
# back up the DYLD_* variables
local BACK=$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH
# unset DYLD_*
unset DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH
# calling sudo
/usr/bin/sudo "$@"
# restore DYLD_* after sudo finished
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=$BACK
}
 
# redirect sudo
alias sudo=thesudo
```

Answer (score 5):

Those who use django (python for web), with mysql through MySQLdb (Mysql-Python module), need that variable set.
So I just keep the warning for now.

Comment: It worked for me with Pinkos answer even though I use MySQLdb

Answer (score 1):

It seems the already mentioned "fixes" are just workarounds that may not work for all users. This is a known bug that Apple is (at least) aware of: http://openradar.appspot.com/11894054

Answer (score 1):

This issue is finally fixed on OS X Mavericks (10.9), the message no longer comes up on sudo.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if this is a true fix, but this error disappeared when I ran Clean Build Folder